# Размещение сайта + приложения Spring на хостинг

Tags: java, spring, хостинг

Требуется разместить на хостинг **сайт**, сделанный на Wordpress и **приложение** Spring. Также нужен **почтовый сервер** для отправки писем из Спринга.

Сайт должен работать на корне домена (example.com).
Приложение на Spring - это просто Rest API, хотелось бы разместить его на поддомене api.example.com, но как я понял для него придется докупать отдельный SSL-сертификат или Wildcard сертификат. Поэтому не критично, если он будет по адресу example.com/api/...

Сейчас я думаю сделать это следующим образом - заказать VPS, установить туда приложение Spring, затем загрузить туда сайт. Отдельно придется докупить почтовый сервер, так как он не идет в комплекте с VPS (по крайней мере на reg.ru)

**Вопрос №1** - Оптимален ли способ, которым я хочу это сделать? может есть менее затратные пути?

**Вопрос №2** - Возможно ли вообще размещение сайта на корне адреса (example.com), а приложения - по адресу example.com/api/ ?

Comment: Сделал то же самое, тоже спринг апп. Сервер 7 долларов в месяц, хост 3 доллара в год (там были и дешевле). Так что не знаю, куда еще бюджетней

Comment: Вам ничего не должно мешать установить почтовый сервер прямо на VPS. Вообще, на VPS в принципе ничего в комплекте не идёт, установить в него все нужные клиенту штуки это ответственность клиента

Comment: И сертификаты покупать не надо, потому что Let's Encrypt выдаёт бесплатные (опять же установить certbot на тот же самый VPS)

Comment: @had0uken, за 3$ в год вы имеете в виду домен?

Comment: А по вопросу №2 не подскажите? каким образом такое можно сделать?

Comment: @Rubix327 ой да, сорри оговорился )